# Setting Up an Integral (depends on displacement vector from a long line)

Tags: integration, physics

The following is a physics problem, but I don't actually care about the physics right now. I just want to set up the integral, which I'm having a difficult time doing (the problem is from the book **2008+ Solved Problems in Electromagnetics**):

[image: The Problem]

The law that we want to use: $$\vec{B} = K \int_C \frac{d\vec{l} \times \vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|^3}$$
$K$ is some constant. $C$ is the wire. $d\vec{l}$ is an infinitesimal length along the wire, and $\vec{r}$ is a displacement vector; where we're calculating $B$. Here's how I'm doing this:

If we define the wire to be $\hat{x}$ where $\hat{y}$ points to the right, then $d\vec{l} = dx ~ \hat{x}$. Any given displacement vector is just $x ~ \hat{x} + y ~ \hat{y} + z ~ \hat{z}$. Then, $d\vec{l} \times \vec{r} = zdx~\hat{y} + ydx~\hat{z}$... right?

So the thing we're integrating is $\displaystyle \int_{L_0}^{L_1} \frac{zdx~\hat{y} + ydx~\hat{z}}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}$ ... ... right?

Since we're just concerned with the 2-D square, $z = 0$ in the displacement vector (because the square is on the xy-plane), so we have: $\displaystyle \int_{L_0}^{L_1} \frac{y}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}dx ~\hat{z}$ ... ... ... right?

This integral evaluates to: $$-y {\left(\frac{\sqrt{L_{0}^{2} + y^{2}} L_{0}}{L_{0}^{2} y^{2} + y^{4}} - \frac{\sqrt{L_{1}^{2} + y^{2}} L_{1}}{L_{1}^{2} y^{2} + y^{4}}\right)}$$

... but I don't think that is right. Am I setting up the integral correctly?

I tried to minimize the physics (to keep it as math as possible). I've been doing integrals for years, and still have a really difficult time setting up what should be even a basic integral—and it's really, really discouraging. I still feel like I have no clue what I'm doing. :/

Comment: I'm a bit perplexed by your approach. The integral you cite initially (Biot-Savart law) is for obtaining the magnetic field; but you can get that much more easily from Ampere's law. After that, you need to compute the magnetic flux through the square. That's a different integral (a surface integral over the square rather than a line integral along the wire.)

Comment: @Semiclassical I dig the magnetic flux part, but isn't Ampere's law only applicable to closed loops of current? I thought I'd have to find the magnetic field generated by the wire, find the magnetic flux through the square, then find the EMF. (Also, even if there is an easier way to do this, is the way I set up my integral... correct?)

Comment: Actually, a long wire is the prototypical application of Ampere's law. Should end up as $\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{1}{r}$ in SI units. But, even in terms of the B-S law that doesn't look like the right integral. Try to break it down a little more: what wire is giving rise to the current, what does $d\vec{l}$ look like, etc...

Comment: @Semiclassical I'm a bit confused. It's the long, straight wire causing the initial magnetic field, and that magnetic field is creating the current in the square wire, right? In the case of the long, straight wire and the Biot-Savart law, $d\vec{l}$ would just be a tiny vector in the direction of the wire (call it the x-direction). I guess I'm having a hard time seeing where I am wrong. (Also, if you place any of your comments in an answer, I'll be glad to upvote/accept it while we continue this discussion.)

Comment: Ok. I'll do that. Though I think I just spotted the issue: the wire extends from $x=-\infty$ to $+\infty$. So while the _flux_ integral should only be along the length of the square, the same isn't true of the B-S integral...

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes!!!! That's exactly what I needed; I was integrating from some dummy-value to some other dummy-value, when I really should have been using negative infinity and infinity. Oh, man. Thank you so much. *Please* put something in the answer section (even if it's just a smiley face, and I'll add the actual answer in a comment) so I can accept it 100 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my last comment above indicates, the issue was a physical one: The magnetic field is produced by the entire wire, not just the portion parallel to the square. (You certainly could have examples where the wire is of finite length, and then the equation you provided would be correct.) Consequently the correct integral is

$$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{y}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}dx =\frac{2}{r}$$

as may be shown by a $x=y\tan \theta$ substitution. (Note that this substitution represents the angle between the $y$-axis and $\vec{r}$.)

Returning to the physics context, this gives a magnetic field of $B=\mu_0 I/(2\pi r)$. We can check that this is consistent with Ampere's law: Take an Amperian loop of radius $r$ which winds around the wire. Since $\vec{B}\parallel d\vec{l}$ for the line element of the loop, the circulation is simply $\oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}=\oint\left(\dfrac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}\right) dl=\mu_0 I$ since the circumference is $2\pi r$. But this is exactly what is required by Ampere's law! (Note that you could have *deduced* $B$ in this manner by making use of the rotational symmetry.)

Comment: One suggestion for practice: Do the Biot-Savart calculation for the field along the axis of a flat current loop. It's a good deal trickier than this calculation, and so will push you more. @AmagicalFishy

Comment: Will do. I maintain a list of problems (this was one of them), and have added that for tomorrow. :) Thank you again